# Bitwise inclusive or in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c

I'm trying to rewrite Obj-C file to Swift. Everything is ok but i can't understand what's that (and how to rewrite it in Swift):

```objectivec
BOOL isSelected = NO;
isSelected |= self.date1 && [self.gregorian isDate:date inSameDayAsDate:self.date1];
isSelected |= self.date2 && [self.gregorian isDate:date inSameDayAsDate:self.date2];
rangeCell.selectionLayer.hidden = !isSelected;
```

I don't see such operator in Swift (i mean `|=`) and i can't figure out what that means. Date is subclass of NSDate in example

Comment: While, as Alexander points out, this really isn’t a case for bitwise operation at all, it’s worth noting that although Swift does support C-style simple integer bitwise operators, bitwise logic is often refactored into [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset/) in Swift. It just depends upon the use case. Obviously, not applicable in this scenario, but just an observation for the sake of future readers who get here on the basis of the title of this question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift does have an `|=` operator. It's briefly mentioned in the Docs under the heading [Operator Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/operator_declarations)

> | Operator | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | ⋮ | ⋮ |
> | `|=` | Bitwise OR and assign |

However, it's not the right operator for the job, even in Objective-C. It happened to work, because `BOOL` bit-wise ORing of two bools happened to be identical to a logical ORing, but that was an coincidence of the implementation details.

In Swift, `|=` is specific to integer types which support bit-wise manipulations. The main implementation of it is defined for `BinaryInteger`. SwiftDoc has better docs on it, [here](https://swiftdoc.org/v5.1/protocol/binaryinteger/#BinaryInteger.%7C=(lhs:rhs:)). For `Bool`, you would use `||=` (which doesn't have a SwiftDoc entry, unfortunately).

Personally, I wouldn't even use `||=`. It works well when you have a long list of conditions, and you want to split their checks between multiple expressions. However, it defeats the short-circuiting behavior of `||`, which I think is worse.

Here's how I would first write this:

```swift
let isSelected =
       self.date1.map { date1 in self.gregorian.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: date1) } ?? false
    || self.date2.map { date2 in self.gregorian.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: date2) } ?? false

rangeCell.selectionLayer.hidden = !isSelected
```

Looking over it, I see that what this is really doing, is checking if `date` is in the same day as `date1` and `date2`, if they exist. It's really just a complicated way to do a range check. So let's do that:

```swift
let selectedDays = [self.date1, self.date2].compactMap { $0 }

let isSelected = selectedDays.contains(where: { selectedDay in
    self.gregorian.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: selectedDay)
})

rangeCell.selectionLayer.hidden = !isSelected
```

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban What's mind-blowing? :)

Comment: Meaning of this. What are we doing here? In obj-c it look like "check for date1 if it's nil. If it's not, AND if date is equal to date1, assign result to isSelected". But look like i got it wrong

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Remember that Objective C played much more fast-and-loose with types. It's C-based, after all :) All non-zero values are "truthy", so the `self.date1` in `self.date1 && ...` is doing a `null-check`. It assumes that null has a `0` value (which is true on the vast majority of systems. There are some odd embedded systems where `0` is a valid pointer, but you're probably not running ObjC on them  ). Then if `date1` exists, it checks that `date` is in the same day (note: not that they're *equal*, just that they're two points in time that share the same day in the Gregorian cal).

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban I've found a better way to express the same thing, check it out.

Comment: yes it's quite concise and clean. However, code still doesn't work as it should with that, but maybe there is an issue somewhere else. Anyway thank you a lot for your answers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237717/discussion-between-alexander-and-evgeniy-kleban).